# 3D list to Numpy array conversion not working, it gives me list object instead

Tags: python, numpy

So I want to convert this list:

`[[[1,2]],[[1,2],[3,4]]]`

to a numpy array.

However it gives me:

`[list([[1,2]]),list([[1,2],[3,4]])]`

Comment: The list is non-rectangular, hendce that is not possible. What would the dimensions be?

Comment: Note that the first sublist is `[[1,2]]` and the second is `[[1,2], [3,4]]`, hence the number of elements per sublist are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list is not rectangular, it wont work